# Effect of over allocating shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, crash, tuning

I have a 9.6 PostgreSQL RDS instance that I am tending to, but did not initially configure, and have been struggling with two different symptoms:

1. the system (a `db.r3.2xlarge` w/ 61GB memory) would experience "cliffs" in freeable memory, dropping 20-30GB almost instantaneously, followed by -
2. an auto-recovery event after some amount of time (could be minutes, could be hours).

On investigation, I found `shared_buffers` set abnormally high, actually exceeding physical memory on the machine. I have reset to a more sane level, but would like some more insight into the expected behavior.

The workload is modest - about a dozen or so concurrent users, manually triggering some large queries (e.g., aggregates on 300+ million row tables). My guess is that those queries trigger the cliffs. My question is about the after effects:

1. Would over-allocating `shared_buffers` explain the stability problems? E.g., PostgreSQL tries to allocate more buffer than the OS has left, the OS says "nope" and things go south from there.
2. Is `shared_buffer` memory ever released back to the OS? For example, I would frequently see a couple idle backends consuming 20-30GB, terminate them, but never see a rise in freeable memory.

Comment: "*Is shared_buffer memory ever released back to the OS*" no. It's allocated during startup and then never released. I _think_ this is different for `work_mem` though.

Answer (score 1):

> Would over-allocating shared_buffers explain the stability problems? E.g., PostgreSQL tries to allocate more buffer than the OS has left, the OS says "nope" and things go south from there.

When the OS says "nope" it's in the system log, and likely the PostgreSQL error log. Just open it up and look. The process should also not start if a bigger allocation is requested than `SHMMAX`. But that value [may not be set properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370985/3285) -- it may be higher than the physical memory.

> On investigation, I found `shared_buffers` set abnormally high, actually exceeding physical memory on the machine. I have reset to a more sane level, but would like some more insight into the expected behavior.

`shared_buffers` doesn't have to fit into RAM. It'll just page. This could be very bad for performance, but I don't know if it would cause the symptoms seen. "Stability problems" are usually hard to define. A bottleneck that reduces memory speed to disk speed can cause all kinds of bad behavior.

Comment: Helpful info. Since the DB is in AWS RDS, I don't have access to system logs, and the postgres.log that AWS captures didn't contain any relevant error messages, only an indication about a "last known up", with corresponding events in the AWS console about recovery starting and finishing. Since reducing the `shared_buffers`, I have not seen any recurrence.